# Rotation animation is causing error...What is Apple's Updated requirement?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, animation, rotation, orientation

What does this mean and why am I getting this error. Any suggestions on how to fix it?

"Using two-stage rotation animation. To use the smoother single-stage animation, this application must remove two-stage method implementations."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The depreciated rotation code in the view controller class had a two step rotation. It rotated half-way, paused, then started again. The new methods do it in one smooth motion. See the UIViewController docs.